# HTTPS vs HTTP on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, https

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/cert.pem'),
    passphrase: '1234567890'
};


http.createServer(app).listen(1156);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8080);


app.get('/',function (req,res){
       res.send('<b>hello</b>');
});
```

When I connect to `localhost:1556` I get the 'hello' text. However when I connect to `localhost:8080` I get a

> localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

error.

Why is this happening? Do I need to use an alternative to app.get??

Comment: you cant test the https side of it via `localhost:8080` but you should be able to use `192.168.x.x:8080` replacing `x.x` for your own ip

Comment: Try to hit the URI with https:// localhost:8080

Comment: @NehaTawar that wont work (atleast from personal testing) as localhost is already secure, which is why it wont work